# The binary relation R is given. Construct the transitive and reflexive closure R * in LISP

Tags: lisp

The binary relation R is given. Construct the transitive and reflexive closure
R *. in LISP  //// how come?

Comment: Can you provide more explanation on what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give much information, but typically, given a relation R, the transitive and reflexive closure of R is a relation R* defined as follows:

- for all X,Y such that R(X,Y), the relation R*(X,Y) also holds;
- for all X,Y,Z such that R(X,Y) and R*(Y,Z), the relation R*(X,Z) holds;

Let's say that you are given a function R that behaves as follows:

- `(funcall R :x X :y Y)` returns a non-nil value iff R(X,Y)
- `(funcall R :x X)` returns all Y such that R(X,Y)
- `(funcall R :y Y)` returns all X such that R(X,Y)
- `(funcall R)` returns a list of (X . Y) pairs for which R(X,Y).

Then you can build a function that computes the transitive and reflexive closure; if you want to know if `R*(X,Z)` holds, you start from `X` and try all possible `Y` that satisfy `R(X,Y)` until either `Y` is equal to `Z`, or you can recursively determine that `R*(Y,Z)`.

After you implement and test that, try to detect cycles too.